# Flexslider with dynamic slides & bullet navigation

Tags: thumbnails, flexslider

I have implemented flexslider with a Drupal site. I am stuck at a point. The problem is my slides are building dynamically as they are configurable from Admin side. Like this:

```
<?php
    $slide_text = '';
    $slide_image = '';
    $slider_nodes = get_slider_nodes(); // get all home page slides
  ?>
  <div id="homepage-slider-wrap" class="clr flexslider-container">
    <div id="homepage-slider" class="flexslider">
      <ul class="slides clr">
        <?php
        foreach($slider_nodes as $slide) :
          $node = node_load($slide->nid);
          $slide_text = $node->body['und'][0]['value'];
          $slide_image = $node->field_slide_image['und'][0]['uri'];
        ?>
        <li class="homepage-slider-slide">
          <div class="homepage-slide-inner container">
            <?php if($slide_text) : ?>
            <div class="homepage-slide-content">
              <div class="clr"></div>
              <div class="homepage-slide-caption">
                <?php print $slide_text; ?>
                <div class="read-more"><?php print l('Read More...' , 'node/' . $slide->nid); ?></div>
              </div>     
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
          </div>
          <img src="<?php print file_create_url($slide_image); ?>">
        </li>
        <?php
          endforeach;
        ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-navigation">
        <div class="custom-controls-container"></div>
    </div> 
  </div>
```

I need slide bullet thumbnails(DIV with "custom-navigation" class) below the  as per the project designs. The problem here is that .read-more  is within a foreach loop, So we what can't put custom-navigation(bullets) inside the any loop. So what is the solution here?

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.